# How can I stop this click event happening at the same time as the previous one? Javascript card game

Tags: javascript, events, click

I currently have this function:

```
function playerTurn() {
    if (playedCards.length == 0) {
        Selection.handSelectionLoop();
        UIC.renderCardInSlot();
        Selection.pushIntoPlayed();
        Selection.checkPlayed()
        Selection.battlePhaseSelect();
    }
}`
```

The intended goal is that a player selects a card from their hand > then plays it in 1 of 5 possible slots > then selects one of the slots for the combat phase of the game (they  could have cards in a different slot that were played in a previous turn that they would like to attack with instead).

`Selection.handSelectionLoop()` adds an event listener to each card in the players hand and adds a `selected` class to each card clicked on (or removes the class if clicked a second time).

`UIC.renderCardInSlot()` adds an event listener to each of the 5 possible slots in the field of play that the cards can be played in. It then renders the card with the `selected` class in the slot when clicked.

`Selection.pushIntoPlayed()` Pushes the object into the `playedCards` array and `checkPlayed()` just checks the cards value (some cards have draw card bonuses).

`Selection` and `UIC` are the modules the functions are saved in.

`Selection.battlePhaseSelect()` adds an event listener to each of the 5 possible slots and adds a `selected-slot` class to the clicked slot.

The problem I'm having is that when a card is played in a slot via `UIC.renderCardInSlot()` it is also adding the `selected-slot` class to it.

What I'd intended to happen is click in the slot to play the card. THEN click to select which slot to proceed with.

How can I achieve this?

(I had tried putting `Selection.battlePhaseSelect()` in an `if else` with `(playedCards.length > 0)` but when the function is called `playedCards` doesn't have anything in it yet.)

`Selection.handSelectionLoop()` is :

```
export function handSelectionLoop() {

    let selectedCardImg = elements.Cards;

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCardImg.length; i++) {

        //add event listener to each card 
        selectedCardImg[i].addEventListener("click", function () {


            if (playedCards.length == 0) {

                //test for the class backface
                if (this.classList.contains("backface")) {
                    console.log(`opponents card`);
                } else if (event.target.classList.contains("card-slot")) {
                    console.log(`select a card from your hand`);
                }

                //test for the class selected
                else if (this.classList.contains("selected")) {

                    //if the img does have the selected class and is clicked, remove the class and remove the corresponding DOMTokenList from the selectedCards array
                    this.classList.remove("selected");

                    selectedCardsImg.shift(this.classList);

                    let thisCard = this.classList[1];

                    for (var i = selectedCards.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                        if (selectedCards[i].cardName == thisCard) {

                            selectedCards.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }


                    //if the img doesn't have the selected class AND the selectedCardsImg array contains no cards, add the selected class to the img and push the DOMTokenList into the selectedCardsImg array
                } else if (!this.classList.contains("selected") && selectedCards.length < 1) {
                    this.classList.add("selected");
                    selectedCardsImg.push(this.classList);
                    emptySelected();
                    //gets the corresponding card object from its classname in DOMTokenlist and pushes it into selectedCards array
                    pushIntoSelected();

                    //if the img doesn't have the selected class AND the selectedCardsImg array contains 1 card, adds the selected class to the img and pushes the DOMTokenList into SelectedCardsImg
                } else if (!this.classList.contains("selected") && selectedCards.length < 2) {
                    this.classList.add("selected");
                    selectedCardsImg.push(this.classList);


                    emptySelected();
                    // removes the corresponding card object from playerHand array and pushes into the selectedCards array
                    pushIntoSelected();
                    //if the suits of both cards match
                    if (selectedCards[0].suit === selectedCards[1].suit) {

                        if ((selectedCards[0].value == "king" ||
                                selectedCards[0].value == "queen" ||
                                selectedCards[0].value == "jack") &&
                            (selectedCards[1].value == "king" ||
                                selectedCards[1].value == "queen" ||
                                selectedCards[1].value == "jack")) {
                            alert("can't play 2 royals together")
                            resetSelected();

                        }
                    } else {

                        //if the suits don't match
                        alert("suits must match");
                        //remove the cards from the selectedCards array
                        resetSelected();

                    }

                }
            }

        });

    }
}
```

`UIC.renderCardInSlot()` is:

```
export function renderCardInSlot() {

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.cardSlotDisplay.length; i++) {

        let cardSlotDisplay = elements.cardSlotDisplay[i];
        //add an event listner (click)
        cardSlotDisplay.addEventListener('click', function () {

            while (playedCards.length === 0) {

                if (cardSlotDisplay.classList.contains("player-offence")) {
                    removeFromHandDisplay();


                    //if the number of cards selected is one 
                    if (selectedCards.length === 1) {

                        let card1 = selectedCards[0]
                        //render this card in the slot
                        cardSlotDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                            `<div class="showcard ${card1.cardName} undercard"></div>
                         <div class="attack-value">${card1.attackValue}</div>
                    `);

                        Selection.pushIntoPlayed();
                        Selection.checkPlayed();





                    } else if (selectedCards.length === 2) {

                        let sharedAttack = Selection.calculateSharedAttack(selectedCards);

                        let card1 = selectedCards[0].cardName;
                        let card2 = selectedCards[1].cardName;

                        cardSlotDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                            `<div class="showcard ${card1} undercard"></div>
                    <div class="showcard ${card2} overcard"></div>
                    `);

                        cardSlotDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                            `<div class="attack-value">${sharedAttack}</div>
                        `)


                        Selection.pushIntoPlayed();

                    }
                } else if (cardSlotDisplay.classList.contains("player-defence")) {


                    //if the number of cards selected is one 
                    if (selectedCards.length === 1) {

                        let card = selectedCards[0].digitValue;
                        let attackValue = selectedCards[0].attackValue;
                        let suit = selectedCards[0].suit;

                        //render this card in the slot
                        cardSlotDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                            `<div class="showcard backface undercard"></div>
                    <div class="attack-value">${attackValue}</div>
                    <div class="facedown-identity">${card} ${suit}</div>
                    `);






                    } else if (selectedCards.length === 2) {


                        let sharedAttack = Selection.calculateSharedAttack(selectedCards);

                        let card1 = selectedCards[0].digitValue;
                        let card2 = selectedCards[1].digitValue;
                        let suit = selectedCards[0].suit;

                        cardSlotDisplay.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
                            `<div class="showcard backface undercard"></div>
                        <div class="showcard backface overcard"></div>
                    <div class="facedown-identity">${card1} + ${card2} ${suit}</div>
                    <div class="attack-value">${sharedAttack}</div>
                    `);





                    }
                }
            }

        })

    }
}
```

and `Selection.battlePhaseSelect()` is currently:

```
export function battlePhaseSelect() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.cardSlotDisplay.length; i++) {

        let cardSlotDisplay = elements.cardSlotDisplay[i];
        cardSlotDisplay.addEventListener("click", function () {

            console.log(event.currentTarget.childNodes[0]);

            this.classList.toggle("selected-slot");

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information/code:
What is the `Selection` class?  
What is the `UIC` class?  
If you wrote them - please show the code.  
If they are a javascript library - please include them in the question's tags.
Most important: show code where `eventListener`s are used.

Comment: Sorry, I've included all of the relevant code above.